# How is "change" calculated in the Stack Exchange reputation leagues?

Tags: support, reputation, statistics, stackexchange, reputation-leagues

In the different [Stack Exchange reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21), like this one below,

[image: excerpt of 2015 math reputation league]

there are nice $\color{green}{\text{+green}}$ or $\color{red}{\text{-red}}$ or $\color{grey}{\text{grey=0}}$ numbers called "change". What is the algorithm behind those figures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those numbers are the "change in rank", determined by the difference between the rank from the previous `$time_frame` and the rank from the `$time_frame` being viewed (where `$time_frame` is either `week`, `month`, `quarter` or `year`).

So from the image, Mike Miller is ranked #161 in the viewed year (turns out to be 2015), and saw a change (in rank) of +20 from the previous year, meaning that he was ranked #181 in the previous year (2014).

[image: Mike Miller reputation league 2014]

Comment: I just don't get that: 181-161=20, 7696-6622=1074. Where does 547 come from?

Comment: @zoli: That should be the difference between the 2014 rank and the [2013 rank](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/year/math/2013-01-01?sort=reputationchange&page=15) (181+547=728). Actually, it's off by one, which is something I can't explain.

Comment: I am still confused: I do not have a 2013 rank. I do have a 2014 rank, 8146. My current year rank is 157. The difference, 8146-147=7989. And my change is 7995.

Comment: @zoli Changes for the current `$time_frame` change [could be the fault of caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). This is not a definitive answer, but [something similar was reported on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261764), which automagically fixed itself. Maybe users who have since been deleted caused this discrepancy? I'm really not certain.

Comment: THX. THX. THX. THX.